# Change Flowable<List<Obj1>> to Flowable<List<Obj2>> in room

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

How can I read a flowable list of values from room and convert it to another object which is a combination of more values from room

```
database.leadsDao().getLeads(leadState.name)
    .flatMap {
        val len = it.size.toLong()
        Flowable.fromIterable(it)
            .flatMap {
                Flowable.zip(
                        database.orderDao().getById(it.orderId),
                        database.orderMedicineDao().getByOrderId(it.orderId),
                        database.patientDao().getById(it.patientId),
                        Function3<Order, List<OrderMedicine>, Patient, LeadDetail>
                        { order, orderMedicines, patient -> LeadDetail.from(it, patient, order, orderMedicines) })
            }
            .take(len)
            .toList()
            .toFlowable()
    }
```

The code above works but I don't like the `take(len)` part. And without it, the stream never calls onNext of the subscriber. The stream keeps waiting for more items, which shouldn't happen since Flowable.fromIterable gives finite number or items and then ends. I.e., the code below **doesn't work**

```
database.leadsDao().getLeads(leadState.name)
    .flatMap {
        Flowable.fromIterable(it)
            .flatMap {
                Flowable.zip(
                        database.orderDao().getById(it.orderId),
                        database.orderMedicineDao().getByOrderId(it.orderId),
                        database.patientDao().getById(it.patientId),
                        Function3<Order, List<OrderMedicine>, Patient, LeadDetail>
                        { order, orderMedicines, patient -> LeadDetail.from(it, patient, order, orderMedicines) })
            }
            .toList()
            .toFlowable()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Flowable.fromIterable gives finite number or items and then ends.

But the `Flowable.zip` inside of the `flatmap` will not end, since Room's DAO objects emit the current value AND all future updates, so the `database.*()` calls that are zipped together are not finite. If you add a `.first()` call to the inner `Flowable.zip` the second version should work as well.

Comment: So, do you recommend using `Single.zip(room.dao().get().firstOrError(), ...).toFlowable()` or is there a better way?

Comment: Rather `.flatMapSingle { Flowable.zip(...).firstOrError() }` seems to fit the problem better